# How do I set a default application that gets used without enquiry?

Tags: default-applications

Say I've got that app that allows me to make phone calls over my private WiFi network ([FRITZ!App Fon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.avm.android.fritzapp) if that matters).

Every time I'm going to make a call, Android asks me which application to use: the (system) phone app or the FRITZ! app. Usually, it's no problem to pick one of the two, but it is problematic when driving: with my Bluetooth equipment, I'm able to start a call without taking the hands off the steering wheel. Better: I **would** be able. Because every time I'm going to start a call, I have to select which app to use.

So I have to pick my phone, unlock it *(while driving)* and select the app to use.

Is there any way to set the default application for a task so that I don't have to pick one every time I want to do something (i. e. always use the system phone app when making calls).

Extra bonus: a rule-based setting would be great (only provide the option to choose that WiFi phone app when I'm actually connected to my home WiFi or when BT is off).

Comment: Sounds like that would be something a Tasker recipe could handle. I'm not a Tasker expert, though.

Comment: @user1: I also got the feeling that it could be done with Tasker but want to know in detail.

Comment: As nice as this sounds: I'm afraid *Tasker* cannot set "default apps" (see below)...

Answer (score 1):

While it cannot switch the default app for something, Tasker can still do this. 
Llama may be able to do it also, but you'll have to set it up like this:

Set the Stock Dialer as default.

Make a tasker profile that enables when you are connected to WiFi and triggers when you open the dialer-- the triggered action could then be to open your WiFi calling app.

I hope that works--

Comment: I'm afraid *Tasker* cannot set "default apps". At least the [User Manual](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/) doesn't list an appropriate action. If you really managed that: Could you please give some more details? The "trigger" is not the issue. But what to specify in the *Task* to make some app "default" for a given action/intent/broadcast?

Comment: @Izzy I don't think you understood rm-vanda's answer. The task isn't to set the default, it's to launch the Wi-Fi app.

Comment: @DanHulme ah, thanks -- now I see. Something like "condition: wifi connected + app launched (dialer)" with the task "start app X". OK, that sounds like a work-around; though the default dialer would still be launched (guess it's running in background anyway, so one could live with that).